# How to convert an array response to json in Angular?

Tags: arrays, json, angular

If I send an HTTP GET request to an API, I get an array as a response:

For example: `[[Peter, 22, 1990], [Dan, 33, 2000]]`.

How can I convert it to JSON?

I want this instead of the array:

`[{"Name":"Peter,"Age":22, "Born":1990}, {"Name":"Dan","Age":33, "Born":2000}]`

Comment: Does the order of columns ever change in the array?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to define your fields manually because Typescript can't guess which field will be the name, or which one will be the age for instance. But if you define the fields, you could do something like this.

```
const data = [['Peter', 22, 1990], ['Dan', 33, 2000]];
const json = data.map(([name, age, year]) => ({ name, age, year }));
```

**BTW**, this has nothing to do with Angular itself, this is a pure javascript question.